# Rails Heroku SSL and Network Solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

Last night I migrated a site to Heroku with Network Solutions.  The process went well for WEBSITE.com and www.WEBSITE.com, but https://WEBSITE.com does not work.  I have the CName "*.WEBSITE.com" set to "WEBSITE.com.herokudns.com." and www.WEBSITE.com set to www.WEBSITE.com.herokudns.com.

Network Solutions said it will take time for the root URL to work through the system.

Comment: If http://website.com works, it isn't a DNS issue. What exactly doesn't work? What is the error that you see? How have you configured SSL on Heroku?

Comment: I configured the SSL on Heroku through Heroku's Automatic "configure SSL".  

https:// WEBSITE.com does not load.  There is no error, just a time out from the browser.  https:// WEBSITE.com will not register in the browser

Comment: error message from browser: "safari can't establish secure connection"